# What is the difference between '>' and a space in CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What's the point using this syntax

```
div.card > div.name
```

What's the difference between this

```
div.card div.name
```

Comment: Further to this question, as I wasn't aware of this and could be used to solve a problem I'm having, which browsers support this type of selector?

Comment: It's supported in all current browsers. IE got support in version 7: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx#combinators

Answer (score 317, accepted):

`A > B` will only select B that are direct children to A (that is, there are no other elements inbetween).

`A B` will select any B that are inside A, even if there are other elements between them.

Answer (score 20):

`>` is the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors). It specifies only immediate child elements.

The white space ( ) is the [descendant selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors). It specifies any descendant (including grandchildren, grand-grandchildren etc.).

The child selector is not supported by IE 6 and lower. A great compatibility table is [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Answer (score 14):

### > vs. Space

Consider the two scenarios `div > span { }` vs. `div span { }`

Here, the   (space) selects all the all the `<span>` elements inside `<div>` element even if they are nested inside more than one element. The `>` selects all the children of `<div>` element but if they are not inside another element.

---

Take a look at two examples:

### > (Greater than):

```css
div > span {
  color: #FFBA00 ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Hello...</span>
      <p><span>Hello!</span></p>
    </div>

    <span>World!</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

This one just selects the `<span>Hello...</span>` (because it's immediately after the nested `div` tag), and `<span>World!</span>` and it won't look for the `<span>` inside `<p>` tag because it's not immediately after a `div` tag.

### Space

```css
div span {
  color: #0A0 ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Hello...</span>
      <p><span>Hello!</span></p>
    </div>

    <span>World!</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

This one selects all the span tags, even if they are nested inside other tags.

Answer (score 4):

`div.card > div.name` matches `<div class='card'>....<div class='name'>xxx</div>...</div>`
but it doesn't match `<div class='card'>....<div class='foo'> ... <div class='name'>xxx</div>..</div>....</div>`

`div.card div.name` matches both.

That is, the `>` selector makes sure that the selected element on the right side
of the `>` is an immidiate child of the element on its left side.

The syntax without the `>` matches any `<div class='name'>` that is a descendant (not only a child) of `<div class='card'>`.

Answer (score 0):

A > B selects B if it's a direct children of A, whereas  A B selects B whether it is a direct children of B or not.

```html
<p> USING SPACE </p>

<style>
  .a .b {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<span class="a">
  a
  <br>
  <span class="b"> a b</span>
  <br>

  <span class="c">
    <span class="b"> a b c</span>
  </span>
</span>

<br><br>
<p> USING GREATER THAN SIGN</p>

<style>
  .x > .y {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<span class="x">
  x
  <br>
  <span class="y"> x y</span>
  <br>

  <span class="z">
    <span class="y"> x y z</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: The demo is nice but really just ancillary to the information which answers the question; information that's already in the other three answers. Maybe if this question were asked today, that'd be useful, but if you're going to necro an >8-year-old question, it should really be for a compelling reason.