# CSS selectors for parent elements

Tags: css

I'm currently reading Charles Wyke-Smith's book "Stylin' With CSS".

He has one section where there is nav.menu > ul {} AS WELL AS nav.menu ul {}.

What's the purpose of the > selector?

Comment: 2nd google result: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Selectors, > versus space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636379/css-selectors-versus-space)

Comment: (or first if you search for "css > selector")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It selects immediate children, as opposed to  descendants at any point in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

**Quick Explanation:**

> E > F    Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

**More detail from the same source:**

> A child selector matches when an element is the child of some element.
>   A child selector is made up of two or more selectors separated by ">".
>
> The following rule sets the style of all P elements that are children
>   of BODY:
>
> body > P { line-height: 1.3 } The following example combines
>   descendant selectors and child selectors:
>
> div ol>li p It matches a P element that is a descendant of an LI; the
>   LI element must be the child of an OL element; the OL element must be
>   a descendant of a DIV. Notice that the optional white space around the
>   ">" combinator has been left out.
>
> For information on selecting the first child of an element, please see
>   the section on the :first-child pseudo-class below.

Comment: Where as the alternative matches any child in the chain rather than any descendant (e.g., child of a child would qualify without the `>`, but not with the `>`).