# Multiple class definitons with space means something?

Tags: css

I found on the web that I can style the HTML with multiple classes using the syntax:

```
.class1.class2 {
    /* style here */
}
```

And I have a big project with css files with the syntax:

```
.class1 .class2 {
    /* style here */
}
```

*(there's a space between the classes)*

Looks like, for me, that this code with space between the classes names are doing nothing... Maybe is an alternative to comment. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In CSS selectors, unlike Javascript for example, whitespace is not ignored.

`.A.B` Will select elements that have both class `A` and class `B`.

`.A .B` Will select any .B class elements that are inside .A class elements.

Example:

```
<A class="A B">
    <B class="A"></B>
    <B class="B"></B>
</A>
```

In this case:

`.A.B` Will return only the `<A class="A B">` element.

`.A .B` Will return `<B class="B">`, as it is a B class element *inside* an A class element.

Sources:

- Stack Overflow: [CSS Selectors, > versus space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2636396/3873012)
- CSS Tricks: [Multiple Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)