# First child TD of a table class

Tags: html, css

I would like to apply some styling only to the first TD of a TABLE with a specific class.
I am using:

```
.class td:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But If there are nested TD they get styled too.

How can I apply this only to the first TD?

[See JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2w4/39/) (I would like test1 to get red, but not test4)

Comment: You don't want to use classes?

Comment: well, I would prefer not to :-) (if possible)

Comment: `.class > tr:first-child > td:first-child` should work.

Comment: This might be helpful info regarding how css selectors work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636379/css-selectors-versus-space

Comment: do you have an idea how to do this in SASS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to use classes or something, you could use the direct child selector:

```
.pretty > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: do you have an idea how to do this in SASS?

Comment: @MaRco85 http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2w4/42/, although it looks better in plain CSS in this case.

Comment: Fantastic. It actually looks better in plain CSS :-D Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Child selector should work with the addition of the `tr:first-child` so your only selecting the first row also.

```css
.pretty > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="logtable" class="pretty">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Payload</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>test4</td>
                        <td>test5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>test1</td>
             <td>test2</td>
             <td>test3</td>
             <td>
                 <table>
                     <tr>
                         <td>test4</td>
                         <td>test5</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>test1</td>
             <td>test2</td>
             <td>test3</td>
             <td>
                 <table>
                     <tr>
                         <td>test4</td>
                         <td>test5</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ive added more table rows so you can see the result of using the `:first-child` pseudo selector on the row.

Comment: amazing. do you have an idea how to do this in SASS?

Comment: Unless you need to style each of those elements individually then I don't think you would need to do it any differently for SASS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), `>`

```
.pretty > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.pretty > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="logtable" class="pretty">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Payload</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>test5</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much..! It's something new to me

Comment: do you have an idea how to do this in SASS?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :

```css
.pretty > * > tr > td:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="logtable" class="pretty">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Payload</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>test2</td>
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>test4</td>
                        <td>test5</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>test1</td>
             <td>test2</td>
             <td>test3</td>
             <td>
                 <table>
                     <tr>
                         <td>test4</td>
                         <td>test5</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>test1</td>
             <td>test2</td>
             <td>test3</td>
             <td>
                 <table>
                     <tr>
                         <td>test4</td>
                         <td>test5</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb2w4/43/).

Comment: @MaRco85 : If you want to restrict your selection to only `td` elements that are part of the tbody, replace the `*` with `tbody`. If you want your code to apply to `th` elements as well, just replace `td` with `th`. etc.