# Change background-color on hover bulma dropdown

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm trying to change the background-color and color of a dropdown element of [Bulma.io](https://bulma.io).

The problem is than no matter what I do it either changes the whole dropdown (also the bottom elements) or it changes only the background of the text (docs) and not the whole box.

I need to change the white box.
I prepared as jsfiddle as example https://jsfiddle.net/agyfL3ae/2/
You will have to enlarge your window a lot as it's hidden on desktop

I've tried the following:

```
/* This changes also the elements below*/

.navbar-item :hover{
    background-color:red !important;
}

/* This changes only the text */

.navbar-link :hover{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Pretty much this is the box I need to change: https://i.snag.gy/pQyME2.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about the <kbd>Space</kbd> in selectors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636379/css-selectors-versus-space)

Basically, that space tells the interpreter to add that background on hover for the children of `.navbar-item`

Instead, you should write:

```
.navbar-item:hover
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the link, I didn't know this difference between spaces. I've removed the space and now is applying the new style only to child elements. I need the opposite effect. Check updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agyfL3ae/3/)

Comment: @Costantin unfortunately, you won't be able to change the parent's style based on child's state using plain CSS. You will have to use JS for that.