# ID and class attributes in Jquery

Tags: jquery

i am new to JavaScript and i do not know what does following mean:

```
  $("#left-pane-tare-button a").show();

$('div#port-picker a.connect').text(getMessage('noconnect')).addClass('active');
```

Comment: *"i do not understand what does "#left-pane-tare-button a" means"*. It means that you need to learn CSS as well. Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: This might also help you understand (https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Comment: thanks,   #left-pane-tare-button a means  get element <a>for all id= left-pane-tare-button ????

Comment: @12345GG: Any `<a>` element that is a descendant of the `id="#left-pane-tare-button"` element.

Comment: @David does you means something like this ???   <a id="#left-pane-tare-button">

Comment: @12345GG: No.  A *descendant*.  For example: `<div id="#left-pane-tare-button"><a ...></a></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a jQuery problem, it is a CSS selector problem.

```
"#left-pane-tare-button a"
```

The selector above is looking for an element with an `id` of `left-pane-tare-button` and selecting all the `<a>` tags that are descendants of the `<div>`.

A space means you are selecting the descendant of the element before the space.

As for

```
'div#port-picker a.connect'
```

A `.` means it is looking for a `class`.

In this case, it is looking for a `<div>` with the `id` `port-picker` and it is selecting all the descendant `<a>` tags that have the `connect` class.

For example:

```
<div id="port-picker">
    <a class="connect">
    <a class="foo">
    <a class="connect">
</div>
```

In this example, it will select the first and third `<a>` tag.

Here are some good resources to learn more about CSS selectors:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

UPDATE: It appears I was wrong about the `>` as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2636396/7351024).

Example:

```
<div id="port-picker">
    <a class="connect">
    <a class="connect">
    <a class="foo">
    <div>
        <a class="connect">
    </div>
</div>
```

Using

```
'div#port-picker a.connect'
```

will select **ALL** `<a>` tags that are descendants of `<div>`

However

```
'div#port-picker > a.connect'
```

will only select **THE FIRST THREE** `<a>` tags that are children of `<div id="port-picker">`, because the fourth one is not a direct child of the original `<div>`.

Comment: Three corrections: *1*) `"#left-pane-tare-button a"` is not looking for a `div`, it is only checking for the `id` attribute. *2*) "A space means you are selecting the child of the element before the space." --- this is incorrect. A space is the "descendant selector", meaning "p em" is selecting _all_ `em` that are descendants of `p` no matter how deeply they are nested. *3*) The `>` is the "direct child combinator", meaning `p > em` will select all `em` that are _direct_ children of a `p` tag (not grandchildren, or further). You may be confusing this with the "direct sibling selector", `+`