# How do I select the third nested list and every other of its sibling lists in css

Tags: html, css

Is there a better way to write this:

```
#container ul ul ul
```

I need to target the third nested list and every other one after that?

Comment: "Better" how exactly?

Comment: You should include an example of the markup you are working with, to better clarify your question, and the answers you get, as well as possibly in image depicting the results you hope to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several ways. If you simply want to assign a css property from the third ul element upwards (i.e.: 3 ul, 4 ul , n ul) the easiest way would be to use an asterisk `*`.

```css
#container ul ul > * {
  font-style: italic
}
```

I have used several selectors in the following example. Which one you actually use is up to you.

```css
#container ul ul ul {
  color: green;
}

div ul > ul > ul {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.third {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#container ul ul > * {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

blockquote {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>I need to target the third nested list and every other one after that?
</blockquote>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>1 ul</li>   
    <ul>
      <li>2 ul</li>   
      <ul class="third">
        <li>3 ul</li>   
        <ul class="third">
          <li>4 ul</li>   
          <ul>5 ul</ul>            
        </ul>        
      </ul>        
    </ul>
  </ul>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. A code dump alone is never as helpful.

Comment: @j08691 You are completely right. I wanted to do this afterwards. I had to do something else for a moment. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent maik, when we have e.g 10 ul nested and use `#container ul ul *` this applied for which ul? third? fourth or all?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Thank you for hint! it must be `#container ul ul > * ` and that applied css properties from the 2 upwards. I inlcuded in the working example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the `>` selector in css or assign the element a `className`, but I don't think there is an easier way to do that rather than these two ways.

By using `>`, you will directly specify the child element (e.g. A) of the parent element (e.g.B) and won't select the appended child element of A.

Check more here: [What is the difference between '>' and a space in CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636379/what-is-the-difference-between-and-a-space-in-css-selectors)

You are trying to get the nested `ul`, so things like  `nth-of-child`  or `nth-of-type` will not work for you.

```css
#ul>ul>ul {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul id='ul'>
  <ul>
    <ul>
      Yes
    </ul>

  </ul>
</ul>
```

Confused with difference between space and `>` in css?

Check this as example:

```css
#ul>ul>ul {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul id='ul'>
  <ul>
    <ul>
      This will be considered
    </ul>
    <div>
      <ul>This will not be considered</ul>
    </div>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

```css
#ul ul ul {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul id='ul'>
  <ul>
    <ul>
      This will be considered
    </ul>
    <div>
      <ul>This will  be considered as well</ul>
    </div>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: But is it better than another?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi, Thanks for telling me that! I have updated the answer to point out the difference between space and `>`. Although `>` looks almost the same as space in CSS, but they are a safer/better way, expecially when you want to choose a specific child element. Check more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636379/what-is-the-difference-between-and-a-space-in-css-selectors

Comment: Thanks. this means that in `A B` styling applies on the `B` even if `B` be the second descendant of A, but in `A > B` does not applies?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi, Nice catch :), you are right (if understand right),  The `>` specifies only immediate child elements and not any descendant (including grandchildren, grand-grandchildren etc.), but space will do

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi, I include two different examples as well to show you the difference and hope not confused you, but we are start to run out of topic lol:)

Comment: very good and excellent:) thanks for your trying:)

Answer (score 0):

the other answers seem to have ignored your other criterion, which was: '*and every other one after that*'

this answers that question

```css
#content ul ul ul:first-of-type,
#content ul ul ul ~ ul:nth-of-type(odd) { color: green;}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <ul>
      <li>two</li>
      <ul>
        <li>three.1</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>three.2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>three.3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>three.4</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>three.5</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

yeap it's messy-looking css (not really, IMHO, but to each their own) but if you don't have access to add classes to the markup, this is the way.